# How to Enable Developer Mode (USB Debugging) for a Gabb Phone Z2?

Tags: installation, usb-debugging, developer-options, gabb

I've been looking around the internet trying to find a way to enable USB Debugging. Looks like there was a way until Gabb patched it. I've tried all of these ways

1. Searching for the autofill on the privacy tab
2. Clicking Build Number 7 Times
3. Typing the code number `*#991#` in the dial option and `*#*#4636#*#*`

Has anyone figured out any workaround for this? I've been searching for any solution and haven't found any, yet. The phone is hackable and there is a way but just don't know yet.

Comment: Based on following this whole cat-and-mouse regarding [tag:gabb] devices, it's unlikely there's a public solution when its manufacturer actively shutting down any new workarounds.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I guessed. I'm am going to try downgrading though because the phone I have did have the older version so hopefully that works.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Gabb Wireless has installed their own ROM on the Gabb Phone and Gabb Phone Plus. When Gabb Wireless rewrote the ROM they removed some system applications that are required for applications like the Google Play Store to run properly(Maps, Side Loading, etc).